# Binding multiple users to people picker control Infopath code behind

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, people-picker

Hi I am using infopath 2010, in code behind we are getting some users from external data source. Now we want to bind these users to a people picker control. meaning if i open the form and i clicked on a people picker control - i should be able to search only from the users who are bind to the control and not others. Any suggestions on this type of binding? [image]

If i bind 4 users from  the code behind to the people picker field - only those 4 users should be allowed to be selected in the people picker control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually people picker control don't work like this, you can bind people picker control to SharePoint security group which contains these four users.. But obviously you can't create a new group each time you want the user to select..

Best is to provide a custom selection view within InfoPath, once selected you can show the selected people in a text box..

Comment: Thanks for the reply - actually those users who i need to bind will come by querying the active directory in code behind(or data connection). is there any way that we can connect the people picker field to web service that queries the AD based on a filter which brings only selected users?

Comment: As I said, you can build your custom view with Repeating Table and make your custom selection method